# Build hierarchized strings

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-2.x

Suppose I have the following method:

```
def _build_hierarchy(*keys):
     # ...
```

If I call `_build_hierarchy('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`, I expect to get the following sequence of `str`:

```
[
    'a',
    'a:b',
    'a:c',
    'a:d',
    'a:b:c',
    'a:b:d',
    'a:b:c:d'
]
```

Notice that hierarchy is based on the order on which I provided the arguments.

To be honest, I have no idea how to approach this.

Ideally, I would like a really simple and pythonic solution if there is such thing.

**Note**: Solution needs to be compatible `Python 2.7`

Comment: is the number of `*keys` variable? Some more decatils on building rules would be nice, they can be deduced, but it's still guessing.

Comment: Why no `'a:c:d'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As for now, it is not clear by which general rule `a:c:d` does not appear in your output. Until precisions are added, this answer assumes it was simply forgotten.*

The desired output is close to being the powerset of your input. We only require that the first element be always present. Thus, we can adapt the [`powerset` function from itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def _build_hierarchy (head, *tail, sep=':'):
     for el in chain.from_iterable(combinations(tail, r) for r in range(len(tail)+1)):
         yield sep.join((head,) + el)


for s in _build_hierarchy('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'):
    print (s)
```

### Output

```
a
a:b
a:c
a:d
a:b:c
a:b:d
a:c:d
a:b:c:d
```

Comment: Also, just to give you a hard time, this includes "a:c:d" which is *not* in OP's example output

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. As for a,c,d I dont understand by which general rule it is excluded, Ill have to wait for OP to add precision

Answer (score 1):

I think it's "the first length-1 keys of item should be continuous, the last key can be isolated." Codes as below:

```
def _build_hierarchy(*keys):
    key_len = len(keys)
    result = []

    if key_len < 1:
        return result

    result.append(keys[0])
    for i in range(2, key_len + 1):
        #the first i-1 should be continuous, the last can be separate.
        pre_i = i - 1
        count = key_len - pre_i

        pre_str = ':'.join(keys[0:pre_i])
        for j in range(0, count):
            result.append(pre_str + ':' + keys[j + pre_i])

    return result


print _build_hierarchy()
print _build_hierarchy('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function:

```
def _build_hierarchy(*keys):
  def combinations(d, current = []):
    if len(current) == len(keys):
      yield current
    else:
      if current:
        yield current
      for i in d:
        if (not current and keys[0] == i) or i not in current:
          if len(current)+1 < 3 or all(c ==d for c, d in zip(keys, current[:len(current)+1])):
            for c in combinations(d, current+[i]):
              yield c
  return sorted([i for i in combinations(keys) if i[0] == keys[0]], key=len)

print [':'.join(i) for i in _build_hierarchy('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a:b', 'a:c', 'a:d', 'a:b:c', 'a:b:d', 'a:b:c:d']
```